# Do you need to put grease on car battery?

Tags: battery

Some cars have grease on the battery terminas and some don't.  I have just replaced a battery.  Is it needed? Why? Can I just go without?

Also I want to clean the top part of my terminals with baking soda and water mix.  Do I have to remove the grease first?

Comment: IF you really want to used a chemical cleaner on the terminals, disconnect the battery, clean everything (battery and connectors), then clean off all the chemicals you used to clean them, then start again with fresh grease. But unless you actually have an electrical problem, this is probably overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grease is there to prevent corrosion on the battery terminals, when you put the connector on and tighten it down the grease gets squeezed out and what's left prevents corrosion where there's no metal to metal contact. If your battery came greased then there's no reason to clean the terminals unless the grease got rubbed off and the terminals corroded. If there's no corrosion there's no need to clean them.

If there's no grease or insufficient grease after tightening then I like to put a dab of vaseline on the top of the contacts to make sure air can't get in.